# operation on array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to extract some elements (say '4') from an array of 'N' elements and create another array of those elemets,ex;
a=[a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6];
I need another array b=[a1 a2 a3 a4] ; How to do this in Matlab?

Comment: Do you mean `b = a(1:4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the first 4 elements from a:

```
b = a(1 : 4);
```

To extract the last 4 elements from a:

```
b = a(end+1-4 : end);
```